# Online Android Development Tutorial / Beginner's Guide?

Tags: android, mobile

Is there a decent online Android development tutorial out there? It seems hard to come by one - I've tried android.developer.com, but the information seems to be scattered and often wrong. I've tried a couple other tutorials (like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidGuide.aspx) and there seem to be errors in every one, as if the author didn't actually try running the program themselves. I'm getting a little frustrated and am looking for a quality guide to android development. Maybe I just have to buy a book.

Comment: You can try http://www.androidpeople.com. It has very good tutorials.

Comment: What a joke => 1. Oftern wrong, 2. there seem to be erros in every one,  3. author didn't actually try running the program themselves

Answer (score 7):

This is a good tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

Then you can find lots of java tutorial and help on the web

Most of the Android-development-tutorial are oriented in some aspects of development
Some are really general like "Hello World" and the others show you a certain part of android development (layout, service, ...)

Don't forget, Google is your friend if you give him the good words

Comment: Flattery will get you everywhere.

Comment: I have personally found a lot of tutorials on Android basics but very few that teaches you to develop a complete app. [Build your first pro Android app tutorial](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/) is really good along with other [Android tutorials](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/).